# Unique identifier for a file picked using file picker in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, file

I am running into a problem while using `video compression` in `iOS`. In my use case, I am picking a file, compressing it and generating its `md5hash`. lets call this f1. If I perform the same steps on the same file and generate the md5hash f2, somehow these hash f1 and f2 are different from each other.

I need to identify if the original files picked by the file picker are same or not (in terms of the data).

One option is to calculate the md5hash for the original file.

I am looking for an alternative option where I could store the unique id associated with a file which would be independent of its name, creation time, etc. Anyone has any idea in this regard?

Comment: Why don't you save these details in persistence storage along with path of respective file?

Comment: since my app deals with files very frequently, it will be a overhead. Maybe the md5 approach is the only path to take keeping in mind my constraints. Thanks for your advice though :)